# Table names not resolving in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, datagrip

I am having quite some trouble wrapping my head around this problem. My WebStorm IDE is not recognizing any tables of my database. I have tried setting `SQL Dialects` and `SQL Resolution Scopes` in Settings but it also doesn't work. Any ideas?

[image: SQL Dialects]
[image: SQL Resolution Scopes]

Comment: Added [tag:datagrip] tag to possibly attract more attention (it should be the same in both of them in terms of configuration).

Comment: Your Dialect/Resolution settings look OK for me. Maybe something can be done in the actual Schema definition?.. Show how Data Source is defined: interested to see the Connection and Schemas tabs (you can blur some private fields if needed). P.S. Material Theme UI -- have it -- very hard to understand what is going on ... You better use some standard theme (light one) for such stuff as some colors may show specific nuances (that otherwise will be left unnoticed in this theme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ummm... Solved it actually ... changed the database connection type from `MySQL` to `MariaDB`. Also, change the `SQL Dialects` and `SQL Resolution Scope` from `MySQL` to `MariaDB`.